# If the characteristic function of a distribution is twice differentiable, then will the density function be continuous?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is from a probability subject.

I'm trying to relate how the differentiability of the characteristic function of a random variable X relates to the density being continuous.

The question specifically is: If the characteristic function of a random variable X is twice differentiable, then will the density function of X be continuous?

Is there any good ways to explain this?

I've tried to think of some counterexamples, such as specific examples from typical distributions of Bernoulli, Binomial, etc but can't seem to find anything that makes sense. Is there a way to generalise this?

Comment: Even an infinitely differentiable characteristic function need not have a density. Smoothness of a  characteristic function is not useful in proving existence or smoothness properties of density even when the density exists.

Comment: Thanks! So the result doesn't hold in general. Is there a counterexample which illustrates this result?

Comment: An example where the density does not exist is $\cos t$.

Comment: If the characteristic function is integrable the there is a continuous density.

Comment: In fact if $X$ is any bounded random variable the characteristic function is smooth.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy it might be helpful to say your $\cos t$ example is for $X=\pm1$ with equal probability